# Collision between AnimatedSprite and Rectangle null pointer error

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to detect a collision between an AnimatedSprite and the Rectangle floor. When they collide, I want the sprite to be removed. However, I keep getting a null pointer error. Am I doing this the wrong way?

Inside my add face function. `face` is an AnimatedSprite created, and `ground` is a rectangle.

```
this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
            @Override
            public void reset() { }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    if(face.collidesWith(ground)) {
                           Debug.d("Contact!");
                           removeFace(face);       
                    } 
            }
    });
```

`removeFace()` is:

```
private void removeFace(final AnimatedSprite face) {
    final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());

    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(face);
    this.mScene.detachChild(face);

    System.gc();
}
```

The null pointer exception is inside `removeFace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the stack trace it will tell you exactly which line has the null pointer exception. You need to invest in [learning to use the debugger](http://byte56devtips.tumblr.com/post/20149822772/debuggers-breaking-bad-code) too, these are simple problems to debug and you can solve your own problems much faster than waiting for a reply here.

From your code I'm assuming that

```
this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face)
```

is returning `null` because it's unable to find the face you specify. So it could easily throw a null pointer exception when it reaches: `facePhysicsConnector.getBody()`. Since you can't access a method of a null object.